# Cabal can't determine GHC version

Tags: haskell, cabal

I am currently trying to update Cabal (1.14.0, cabal-install at version 0.14.0) by doing

```
cabal install cabal-install
```

However, this gives me an ExitFailure1 with the error

```
setup: The program ghc version >=6.4 is required but the 
version of /usr/bin/ghc could not be determined.
```

But I'm definitely running a version of GHC that is greater than that.

```
$ /usr/bin/ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.2
```

It might be important that I'm on OSX 10.8 and that I installed Haskell through the Haskell Platform download for Mac.

Does anyone have advice on how to fix or work around this issue? I haven't been able to find any documentation on this problem.

Comment: Does running cabal with `-v`, `-v2` or `-v3` give any hints?

Comment: @bennofs -v3 revealed [how it's supposed to be getting the version](http://hastebin.com/raw/gukaqevupe), using the --numeric-version flag, but this confuses me even more since running /usr/bin/ghc --numeric-version gives back the output "7.4.2".

Comment: what happens when you try `cabal update`?

can you also give us output to your $PATH directory? you might need to point to your ghc location

Comment: You could also grab the `bootstrap.sh` script from [here](https://raw.github.com/haskell/cabal/cabal-install-v1.18.0.2/cabal-install/bootstrap.sh) and run it. That installs cabal without depending on cabal. Maybe that works.

Comment: @katychuang Running "cabal update" just tells me that my cabal-install is out of date. Also, I think the output from -v3 implies that this isn't a pathing issue, since it's finding the correct executable for ghc.

Comment: @bennofs The bootstrap.sh script isn't working for me either, it's 404ing on the URL to fetch the package for Cabal. Investigating the issue now, might be [related to this](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/1521).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on a Mac, why not try installing the excellent [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) package manager? Add `/usr/local/bin` to your PATH, and then it's just `brew install cabal-install`.

You can even `brew install ghc haskell-platform`.

To upgrade the package list, use `brew upgrade`, then you can see what needs updating with `brew outdated` and update them with `brew update`.

Of course, you can name individual packages to update also, and specify versions of packages. Homebrew keeps the "recipes" (Ruby scripts) for package management in its own git repository (by default in /usr/local).

Then you can get on with what you really wanted to do in the first place...write some code! (or build, in your case)

Comment: Didn't realize Homebrew had formulas for the haskell-platform and cabal. This worked, thanks so much!